# NoMethodError in Bank_accounts#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to learn Ruby on Rails by creating a project and I can't seem to get my head around an error I keep getting. If I don't get the "NoMethodError", I'll get something like "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!" - I simply want to view a bank account and have it show the transactions on that bank account. My problem may be with the controller, but I've tried all sorts of different things and can't figure it out. Much help would be greatly appreciated. I think I've included everything, if not, I apologise and will include what ever else is needed.

**Bank Account Controller Show (I think the error is in the show):**

```
def show
  @bank_account = BankAccount.find(params[:id])
  @transactions = @bank_account.transaction

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @bank_account }
end
```

**Views: bank_accounts>show.html.erb**

```
<% @transactions.each do |transaction| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=h transaction.transaction_id %></td>
    <td><%=h transaction.dateD %></td>
    <td><%=h transaction.trans_type %></td>
    <td><%=h transaction.amount %></td>
    <td><%=h transaction.new_balance %></td>
    <td><%=h transaction.transaction_success %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', transaction %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_transaction_path(transaction) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', transaction, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I think this is the backtrace (sorry for not including it).
"BankAccount/app/controllers/bank_accounts_controller.rb:17:in `show'"

Also, if I do the following for the bank account controller:

```
def show
  @bank_account = BankAccount.find(params[:id])
  @transactions = @bank_account.transactions

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @bank_account }
end
```

I get this SQL error:
"ActiveRecord::JDBCError: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: transactions.bank_account_id): SELECT * FROM "transactions" WHERE ("transactions".bank_account_id = 1)"

Comment: Can you post the backtrace? It should lead you to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your BankAccount model has many transactions, the method to access them is plural:

```
@transactions = @bank_account.transactions
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried both of these, and no luck, I get a "undefined method `transactions' for #<Array:0xa70099>"

Here's my models:
bank_account.rb
`class BankAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions
end`

transaction.rb
`class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bank_account
end`

Comment: maybe BankAccount.find is returning nil

Comment: If I use "BankAccount.find(:all)" in the rails console it returns all the data. And if I use "BankAccount.find(1)" it returns data. So surely it's not returning nil?

Comment: and if you give "BankAccount.first.transactions" ?

Comment: I seem to get this error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: ActiveRecord::JDBCError: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: transactions.bank_account_id): SELECT * FROM "transactions" WHERE ("transactions".bank_account_id = 1)

Comment: you didn't put the column bank_account_id on the transactions table, you have to create the migration. read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is that the `BankAccount.find` is returning `nil`. Then, on the next line, you are trying to access the `transaction` method on `@bank_account`, which throws the error.

Make sure that `params[:id]` has the correct value.

Comment: If I use "BankAccount.find(:all)" in the rails console it returns all the data. And if I use "BankAccount.find(1)" it returns data. Shouldn't params[:id] get changed based on if I have for example http://localhost:8080/bank_accounts/1 ?

Furthermore, if I use @bank_account = BankAccount.find(1) I still get this error: "ActiveRecord::JDBCError: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: transactions.bank_account_id): SELECT * FROM "transactions" WHERE ("transactions".bank_account_id = 1)"

Comment: did you run `rake db:migrate` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at your model code and your migration code.
In order to have @bank_account.transaction to return the transaction, the two of them must have one-to-one relationship.

Your bank_account model should have

```
has_one :transaction
```

Your transaction should have

```
belong_to :bank_account
```

Your migration script when creating transaction table should have something like

```
transaction.references :bank_account
```

The reference will create the field bank_account_id in your transaction table.
I think it explain why you have error that "no such column: transactions.bank_account_id)"